# Appended message to div not showing in dialog

Tags: jquery

I cannot get my appended messages to show in a dialog. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t87wdg0d/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="errorMessageContainer" title="Required Fields" class="alignLeft" 
    style="padding: 5px; margin: 0;">
    <p id="errorMessage"></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var errorMessages = ["First Error Message", "Second Error Message"];
var message = "";

$.each(errorMessages, function (key, value) {
    message += "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-bullet'>" + value + "</span><br />";
});

$("#errorMessage").append(message);

$(function () {
    $("#errorMessage").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The classes `ui-icon ui-icon-bullet` are causing the problem. Remove them and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks...that was too simple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the classes `ui-icon` and `ui-bullet`,

Tweak your code to this,

```
$.each(errorMessages, function (key, value) {
    message += "<span><i class='ui-icon ui-icon-bullet'></i>" + value + "</span><br />";
});
```

The class css was hiding the text inside the `<span>`. Added an additional element `<i>` to it.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I just had.

Answer (score 0):

You'r code is fine it's you css thats hiding your text. Remove your text from ui-icon and place it in another span after the icon span.